# Transcendental distance sets

Tags: set-theory, geometric-measure-theory, rational-points

Define a set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ as a
*transcendental distance set* if the distance between any pair of
distinct points of $S$ is transcendental.
For example, $S = \{ k \, \pi \;\mid\; k=1,2,\ldots \}$ is such a set in $\mathbb{R}^1$.

> ***Q1***. How large can a transcendental distance set be in $\mathbb{R}^d$?

The above $S$ is countably infinite. What is an example of an uncountably infinite $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^1$, and more generally in $\mathbb{R}^d$?
It would seem that random sets should be transcendental distance sets.

Suppose one further filters, in $\mathbb{R}^d$ requiring that the area of all triangles
determined by $3$-point subsets be transcendental, the volume of all tetrahedra
determined by $4$-point subsets be transcendental, and so on up to 
the measure of $d+1$ simplices.
Call such a set a *transcendental measure set*.

> ***Q2***. How large can a transcendental measure set be in $\mathbb{R}^d$?

I know there is work on "Avoiding rational distances"
(e.g., Ashutosh Kumar. *Real Analysis Exchange* 38.2 (2012): 493-498.)
that may answer my questions, but I have not yet seen direct implications.

Comment: If you assume axiom of choice, I believe it's straightforward to use transfinite induction to construct transcendental-distance set of size continuum. I'm not sure, but I'd expect it to generalize to transcendental measure sets for any $d$.

Comment: If you believe that all algebraic irrationals are normal numbers, then if you take the set of all real numbers in [0,1] whose decimal digits are 5's and 6's say, then differences of this set are not normal numbers (they have no 3s in their expansion for example) and so cannot be algebraic. On the other hand, you cannot have a positive measure set because differences of positive measure sets contain intervals.

Comment: You can use Zorn's lemma and measure theory. Suppose $S$ is a maximal subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with no algebraic volumes - one exists by Zorn's lemma. Let $D$ be the set of all points $z$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $z$ forms a simplex of algebraic volume together with some $n$ points of $S$. Since the set of $n$-tuples of points of $S$ is countable, and the set of algebraic numbers is countable, you see that $D$ is a union of a countable collection of hyperplanes, thus has measure zero. This means that there is a point in the complement to $D\cup S$, so $S$ is not maximal - contradiction!

Comment: The same sort of argument can be used if you're avoiding any countable collection of algebraic relations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23202/explicit-big-linearly-independent-sets) question provides an algebraically independent set of real numbers of size continuum. Enumerate it as $\alpha_{i,r}$ where $i\in\{1,...,d\},r\in\Bbb R$. Now define set $S=\{(\alpha_{1,r},...,\alpha_{d,r}):r\in\Bbb R\}\subseteq\Bbb R^d$. Now, measure of any simplex with vertices on these points can be expressed using coordinates of the vertices and radicals. If any of these turned out to be an algebraic number, we would have a non-trivial algebraic relation between $\alpha_{i,r}$, which is not possible, as they are algebraically independent.

As $|S|=\frak{c}$, we see that transcendental measure set can have size $\frak{c}$. By taking subsets of $S$, we can get transcendental measure set of any size at most continuum, and, clearly, not of any greater cardinality.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the link to the $\frak{c}$-sized algebraically independent set of reals.