# Nice partition of $\mathbb{R}$ into uncountably many uncountable sets

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

A recent issue of *American Math. Monthly* has a paper that partitions
$\mathbb{R}$ into an arbitrary finite number of uncountable sets such
that every real number is a condensation point of all the sets in the
partition. In fact, we can find uncountably many uncountable
subsets $S_\alpha$ of $\mathbb{R}$ that are (1) pairwise disjoint, (2)
have union $\mathbb{R}$, and (3) every real number is a condensation
point of all the sets. One way to do this is the following. For any
infinite binary sequence $\alpha=(a_1, a_2, \dots)$, let $S_\alpha$ be
the set of all real numbers whose fractional part has the binary
expansion $0.b_1b_2\cdots$ such that the sequence
$(b_2,b_4,b_6,\dots)$ differs from $\alpha$ in only finitely many
terms. When $\alpha=(1,1,1,\dots)$ we must remove from $S_\alpha$ all
numbers whose binary expansion ends in infinitely many 1's, due to the
nonuniqueness of the binary expansion. The set of distinct
$S_\alpha$'s then has the desired properties. This partition of
$\mathbb{R}$ also has the property that any two of the sets $S_\alpha$
and $S_\beta$ are translates of each other, except for
$S_{1,1,1,\dots}$. This suggests the question: does there exist a
partition of $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying (1), (2), and (3) such that
*every* pair of sets in the partition are translates?

Comment: (Not very constructive)  $\mathbb{R}$, as a vector space over  $\mathbb{Q}$, may be decomposed in direct sum of $\mathbb{Q}$-vector subspaces, $S\oplus T$, both of continuum dimension. Then we can take $S_\alpha:=S+\alpha$ for $\alpha\in T$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the following works:

Fix an uncountable subgroup $G$ of $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ - note that any such is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and in fact intersects each nonempty open interval uncountably often - of uncountable index, and consider the set of cosets of $G$.

(Such a group can be produced by transfinite recursion using a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$: alternate between throwing reals into the group, and barring reals from entering the group.)

---

Note that the argument above relies on the axiom of choice. However, this isn't necessary: [provably in ZF, there is a $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent set $S$ of reals of size continuum](https://mathoverflow.net/q/282832/8133). We can split this into two disjoint sets $S_1, S_2$ of size continuum (pick some appropriate real $a$ and consider the points to the left of $a$ versus the right of $a$). Now consider the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space generated by $S_1$.

Comment: It might be worth crediting @PietroMajer's comment for the idea in your edit.

Comment: @GregMartin My answer actually preceded that comment - note the timestamps.

Comment: Your answer did, but the second section was added after the comment.

Comment: @GregMartin The content of the second section was the provability of the claim *without choice*, which was not present in the comment. My answer was not dependent on or inspired by the (quite correct) comment in question.

Comment: (And in fact I didn't see Pietro's comment until you pointed it out to me.)