# The set-theoretic multiverse as a (bi)category

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, set-theory, categorical-logic, multiverse-of-sets

Joel Hamkin's [The set-theoretic multiverse](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4223) has featured in MO questions before, e.g., [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25227/using-the-multiverse-approach-to-decide-the-law-of-the-exluded-middle) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39604/universe-view-vs-multiverse-view-of-set-theory). But I was wondering about the best category theoretic angle to take on it.

In the paper Joel writes, rather poetically,

> Set theory appears to have discovered an entire cosmos of set-theoretic universes, revealing a category-theoretic nature for
>   the subject, in which the universes are connected by the forcing relation or by large cardinal embeddings in complex commutative diagrams, like constellations filling a
>   dark night sky. (p. 3)

He has given us a couple of kinds of morphism here, but what is the best way to capture this multiverse category theoretically? Which morphisms should we allow?

Is it right to stay at the level of ordinary categories? Since each universe, a model of ZFC, is a category, one might expect the multiverse to be at least a bicategory, as suggested [here](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/08/the_settheoretic_multiverse.html#c039277). Do set theorists consider, say, arrows between two forcing relations between two models?

Comment: What do you mean by "a model of ZFC"? Are you assuming the existence of inaccessible cardinals or working in a 'background' theory which allows proper classes?

Comment: It's a standard expression. There's been plenty of discussion at MO already as to what models of ZFC are, e.g., http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13609/models-of-zfc-set-theory-getting-started/14625#14625, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15685/is-it-necessary-that-model-of-theory-is-a-set/15712#15712 and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28869/how-to-think-like-a-set-or-a-model-theorist/28881#28881.

Comment: I clicked on this thinking I was going to get some "physics" style question of the sort Peter Woit despises. How about saying 'set-theoretic multiverse' in the title? Just a personal quibble...

Comment: @David Roberts: rest assured that if it were that sort of question, it would be closed within minutes. The MO regulars run a pretty tight ship. :-) 

Comment: Yes. I was on my way here to do just that ... :P

Comment: Asdf over here - http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/08/the_settheoretic_multiverse.html#c039268 - was averse to any use of 'multiverse'. I'll see if I can qualify it in the title.

Comment: @David C - did you want to add the tag [multiverse-of-sets] to this question? I created it for my new question which relates to this one, it could be handy.

Comment: A recent, relevant paper: Alec Rhea, An axiomatic approach to the multiverse of sets, https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.03169.

Answer (score 12):

First of all, thank you very much for the question (the attention given to my multiverse article is flattering).  I am keenly interested to hear from the category theorists about this.  Meanwhile, allow me to comment from a set-theoretic perspective.

Although set-theorists seldom use category-theoretic terminology and ideas explicitly, nevertheless many of their concerns do have a category-theoretic nature. To give two examples:

- It is a fundamental concern in the theory of large cardinal embeddings to understand when the direct limit of a system of iterations of large cardinal embeddings has a well-founded direct limit, and this issue can be cast category-theoretically as the question of whether a certain category exhibits certain limits.
- The choice of support in an iterated forcing argument, pervasive in set theory, amounts to the use of certain limits in certain categories.  For example, the fact that ccc forcing is preserved under finite support iterations can be expressed category-theoretically as the category of ccc forcing notions having direct limits. Other choices of support, such as countable support or Easton support (a mixture of inverse limits and direct limits) or revised countable support, can similarly be cast category-theoretically. Much of our understanding of the power of forcing has come from a detailed analysis of the nature of these different types of iterations.

Even the forcing combinatorics of single forcing notion $\mathbb{P}$, such as the question of closure, chain condition and homogeneity properties, can be cast category-theoretically.  Some forcing constructions, such as the stationary tower forcing, combine all the category theoretic ideas above, as the conditions in the forcing involve generic embeddings that are iterated and extended.

In each of these cases, the set-theoretic ideas relate directly to features of the class of all models of set theory that might arise from the construction at hand. In the case of iterated large cardinal embeddings, one is led to consider the models of set theory that arise during the course of the iteration.  And in the case of forcing iterations, one of course considers the intermediate forcing extensions that arise from the factors of the forcing iteration. Many set theoretic arguments involve a vast assemblage of intermediate models of set theory connected in a certain precise manner, either by forcing or by large cardinal embeddings, and the analysis of this system is driving the argument.  It was in part his kind of situation that I had in mind in the remarks that you quoted.

But another aspect was the observation that set theorists have discovered a huge abundance of models of set theory, with new universes often constructed from known universes in certain precise manners. So the natural inclination when viewing the multiverse as a category, therefore, would be to have an absurdly generous concept, where all the models of set theory appear as the objects, and all of the known ways that they can relate appear as morphisms, including elementary embeddings, the forcing extension relation, embeddings from one model to an inner model of another, the end-extension relation, and so on.

But such an absurd idea, of course, is not how one generally makes progress with category theory. Rather, one wants to choose the objects and morphisms carefully so that the category exhibits desirable features, which can then be fruitfully employed.  So, my question for the category theorists would be: what are the category theoretic properties that we might aspire to exhibit in the multiverse?  An answer might guide one to a fruitful choice of morphisms.

Comment: Note that we might have not just a category but an $n$-fold category for some $n$ which is the number of currently known different kinds of morphisms between models/universes, or at least the ones we are interested in for the purposes of the exercise (see http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/n-fold+category).

Answer (score 1):

**To Begin:** There are two notions we need to clearly distinguish here: first, the principles which are suspected (or asserted) to hold in the multiverse; and second, the actual intended interpretations of these principles and the implicit bounds placed on them by living in a particular $V$.

First, the principles he discusses are first order, which means they live in the world of math proper. Moreover, they are nice, and in fact there is a rather nice model for them. However, this model and any other such model, can in no way reflect anything other then the first-order principles which are asserted to hold in the multiverse. They are simply objects which exhibit the consistency/coherence of said principles (kind of like exhibiting $\{0\}$ with the operation $\{\langle\langle 0, 0 \rangle,0\rangle \}$ and noting that it satisfies the axioms of a group.)

Second, under the intended interpretation, there can be no actual *object* which is *the* multiverse. This follows directly from the Forcing Extension Axiom. The reason being: it is impossible to internally "close off" a forcing notion, because by asserting a particular generic exists, you have just defined how to get around it. More succinctly put, for any separative $\mathbb{P}$, if $G$ is $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $V$, 
then $G$ is not $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $V[G]$ (since $1 \Vdash \forall \dot{p}\in\check{\mathbb{P}} \,\exists\dot q\in (\check{\mathbb{P}}\backslash \dot{G})(\dot{q}\le\dot{p})$.) Moreover, the "Absorption into L" and "Countability Principle" combine to imply that any $V$ which thinks it has captured the multiverse, is only lying to itself.

**My Main Point:**  The proper multiverse is a flat out, meta object, in the strongest sense possible. The reason for this: you officially cannot get out in front of it, or out run the strength of its intended interpretation (like you can do with inaccessible cardinals and ZFC.)

**Addendum:** see comments.

**Note:** If there is an issue please let me know in the comments

Comment: 2-categories are first-order as well...And since a ZFC-category is a model of ETCS (also a first-order theory), everything David C is talking about is first order. I would like to be told where my naive idea is going wrong.

Comment: David, the problem is the other way around. The set-theoretic multiverse is usually not first-order. For example, set theorists generally prefer well-founded universes, which is not a first-order concept.

Comment: I'm not understanding how any of this is addressing David Corfield's question: what, conceptually, is an appropriate notion of morphism between universes in a multiverse (and, going further, what is the appropriate notion of 2-morphism between morphisms)? For example, one could posit logical functors between the underlying toposes of universes of sets as morphisms, but how appropriate would this be for capturing salient aspects of Joel's program? (Despite David C.'s use of the word "capture", I didn't think he was hoping to characterize "the" multiverse by asking such a question.) 

Comment: @Todd, the discussion relating to Joel's answers to this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42710/how-do-we-compare-models-of-etcs does a much better job explaining the difficulties, even under the restricted notion of ETCS, than I personally can.

Comment: I also can't see in what way this is an answer to the question.


Comment: @Michael, the discussion you mention in your comment gives reasons for thinking that requiring arrows to be logical functors is too restrictive. But that still leaves my question unanswered.

Comment: @David, the forcing construction is centered on establishing the consistency of logical statements, and in a sense, we do not care about particular generic extensions beyond there logical properties. That having been said, the logical properties a particular extension possess does not tell us how it was constructed. Which given the intent of the multiverse (as a collection of distinguished members of equivalence classes defined by elementary equivalence) implies that there is no way to reconcile the two notions favorably.

Comment: Michael, I'll second David C.'s comment: that discussion merely shows that logical morphisms might not be the best thing to consider. Your point 2 in the addendum seemingly attempts to say something much stronger, that *in principle*, based on "ontology", category theory can have nothing useful to say about a notion of multiverse. That point didn't make a lot of sense to me: considering Grothendieck toposes as universes (which is in line with Joel's ideas), it would also predict that there is no useful notion of morphism between Grothendieck toposes. Which is false! (Geometric morphisms) 

Comment: @Todd @David, First, the multiverse is presented in a manner dealing only with elementary equivalence (this is clearly stated in the axioms.) As such the only type of morphism consistent with capturing the intent of the multiverse is one which describes elementary equivalence, and is not element based (which discounts the use of a geometric morphism.) Second, the elements of the particular models in the multiverse do not and cannot exist simultaneously within one single $V$ (each $V$ sees only a small fragment of the mv) which implies that you cannot faithfully represent the entire mv n a $V$.

Comment: @Todd, What I've said is that the closure properties of **the** multiverse are incompatible with any object which can be fully positioned inside a single $V$. This is why I took the time to talk about the first-order properties Joel lists and point out that the model he produced for them, is in his own words "a toy." In other words: The actual intented interpretation of the multiverse transcends naive notions like set and class. Which implies that any model which you can exhibit and claim is the multiverse, is by default not the multiverse.

Comment: @Todd, (continued) In particular, this applies to objects like categories, and their extensions. 

Comment: @Todd, What is actually happening here is akin to the following observation: Provided $ZFC$ is consistent there can be no model for $ZFC+\neg Con(ZFC)$, yet $ZFC+\neg Con(ZFC)$ is consistent. Its a catch 22 that you cannot get around. 

Comment: @Michael - I think you don't understand what David C is asking. He is not asking if one can model the multiverse in a universe, and as I pointed out, the definition of a 2-category is first order, so we don't need an ambient set theory in which to 'place' it. From a ct point of view one _shouldn't_ ask that elements of different models live in a single $V$, and this is the position I'm guessing David is taking. 

Comment: What one can ask, I would hope, is that given two universes (which are 'objects' of the multiverse), what sort of maps between them are there, that reflect the fact they are universes? We don't need to consider the whole multiverse for this exercise.

Comment: "Usable formulations of the naive notion of Category are presented as internally definable objects, in the sense that you must be in some V or have a particular V in mind before you can actually make use of the notions and tools of the theory" this is not true, else ETCS as foundation would be impossible.

Comment: Yes, David R. is expressing my position. I'm simply asking what we should think of what Joel said about commutative diagrams. He's talking about arrows and an identity between compositions of arrows. I want to now what kinds of arrow we could usefully consider, and whether we can relate arrows between a pair of objects other than by identity, i.e., by 2-arrows.

Comment: What I'm saying is that: the existence of the "arrows" changes depending on the ground model, and makes the notion ill-defined and useless in a global setting.

Comment: The best example of this: Suppose $\kappa$ is supercompact in $V$, then $\kappa$ is not supercompact in $V$'s associated inner model $L$.   Putting the combinatorics aside, this means that $L$ fails to capture the most of the embeddings ("arrows") which witness $\kappa$ is supercompact.

Comment: So my question to the both of you is: Which $V$ are you going to use to decide there is an arrow between two universes?

Comment: (feel free to replace V with model of ETCS because the same problem exists)

Comment: Finally, the only notion of arrow that makes any sense is that defined by elementary embedding, which as I've stated, is not going to capture relationships between forcing extensions, and has its own difficulties when you note that as stated in the proposed axioms, the existence of such an embedding must be witnessed from the perspective of a particular universe, containing the ones under discussion. 

Comment: "Finally, the only notion of arrow that makes any sense is that defined by elementary embedding" -- what makes you so sure? Perhaps we should hear from Joel at this point (instead of dragging out an endless discussion in comments), so I'll bow out in just a moment, but: it probably depends on what you want to do. E.g., in view of a nice paper by Andreas Blass, one might be interested in *exact* functors between categories of sets. What sorts of exact functors exist indeed reflects interesting set-theoretic properties, but far less restrictive than if one chose elementary embeddings as maps. 

Comment: With regard to the fact that existence of (some posited notion of) arrow between some pair of universes may depend on the properties of the "super-universe" in which a multiverse is regarded as living, my reaction is: so what? My expectation is that one will be primarily interested in arrows (whatever they are chosen to be) that can be *proved* to exist based on the multiverse axioms (whatever they are exactly), i.e., in those that exist independent of super-background. But no matter: this issue is completely orthogonal to David's question, which is a conceptual question.  

Comment: In regards to your first comment: in order to maintain the intent of the multiverse and remain coherent with its proposed axioms (which only make use of elementary equivalence/submodel and elementary embedding.) In regards to your second comment: There is **no** "super-universe" which can capture the multiverse. And finally, non-identity universal elementary embedding cannot be "proven" to exist without strong higher order background assumptions.

Comment: The question asked about the multiverse, not about some toy model of universes you call the multiverse. This is the view I've taken, and what I've said is coherent with that assumption. And yes, **Other** notions of arrow between universes make sense, and can tell you set-theoretic information, but these things are distinct from, and not in keeping with the intent outlined in that paper.

Comment: Michael, you kept asking "which V are you going to use?"; I assumed that that V meant some background in which to speak of *a* multiverse. That background is what I was calling a super-universe (faute de mieux). Sorry if I misunderstood. More importantly, while I wasn't able to extract an axiomatic theory of multiverse from Joel's paper, the proofs (without scare quotes) would prefer to proofs which proceed from those axioms. (Philosophically, I don't have faith in "the multiverse" or "a multiverse" as a Platonic entity, but I do put stock in mathematical proofs which proceed from axioms.)

Comment: I apologize for any ambiguity in what I've said. Just wanted to add: the multiverse view is designed to be the anti-pure platonist position (which in this case is the universe or ultimate-L view.) The underlying premise here is that the multiverse cannot be positioned in a way which allows it to be captured by any single universe (otherwise it would make a horrible counter-point to the ultimate-L view.) The list of principle Joel outlines at the end accomplish this rather nicely by proposing it be viewed as some kind of backward reflection scheme (where the new univ contains the old.)

Comment: Michael, I agree with your main point (+1), and the discussion brings out what I find (and discuss in my paper) to be a major issue with the formalization of questions concerning the multiverse. Although many questions about the multiverse are first-order expressible within the individual universes of the multiverse, some of the troubling questions are not. And for these, we fall back on the toy model formalization. So let us take David's question here in the context of the toy model formalization. That is, in multiverse of toy models, viewed as a category, what should the morphisms be? 

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to think what would be the starting point and a basic program to "categorize" the multiverse.

Let us  begin with the [accessible category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessible_category) MOD(ZF) of all models of ZF and usual maps of models. Now, obviously, there is something there that makes it distinguished from other analogous cat of models of first-order theories (say GROUPS).

As Joel has reminded us above, there is a plethora of technologies to build models out of existing ones, either by enlargement (forcing), or by restriction (inner models).

My immediate reaction (from the categorical standpoint) is this:

**can we characterize these operations STRUCTURALLY?**

I mean: can we, without resorting to the usual set-theoretical details of such constructions, describe them (for instance the various types of  forcing enlargements) in a purely diagrammatic way within MOD(ZF)? That would be, or so it seems to me, step one (this step may require to introduce additional maps, in which case it can guide us toward the proper set-up).

Asssuming that one can partially answer in the affermative, step two would be:

**axiomatize MOD(ZF) as an accessible category PLUS those structural operations.**

Step three would be this: unlike other MOD(T) categories, MOD(ZF) has this fascinating property: given a model M of ZF, ie an element of the cat,

**one can onsider the MULTIVERSE of internal models of M** (let us call it the  chinese boxes principle, if there is no name already).

That seems to suggest, as the PO has in fact hinted at,  that MOD(ZF) is in fact a higher cat.

The game is not over. There is a subtle interplay between those internal models and their externalization. Here I have no clue, but it looks like the proper line of thought would be to use the machinery of internal category theory to express this feature.

Step four (excuse me, I am talking free-wheeling) would be: now, given the full axiomatization of Mod(ZF), is there some way to prove that is "unique"? Or are there other models of this axiomatization which are not MOD(ZF)? Most likely there would be other (multi)universes which are not the  intended one.

POST SCRIPTUM: I am no expert, so the set-theory adepts should correct me if in the loose sketch of the program above I introduced some unintended nonsense. In particular, I assumed a broad threefold partition of model-building tools, into enlargement, restriction (such as  L and variants thereof) and finally internalization (ie starting from a model M create another one which happens to be a set in M). If there is something which does not fit the mentioned labels,add it (them) to the menu. For instance, There are (at least) two types of enlargement, one which keeps the tallness fixed, and another type which makes the model taller. A structural approach to model building inside the multiverse has to account for all those types, so a preliminary accurate taxonomy of basic model building shapes is in order.

Comment: Compare algebraic set theory, where there is a monad $ZF$ on a 'category of classes' such that free algebras for this $ZF$ are precisely models of ZF(C). See e.g. http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+set+theory and references there.

Comment: Thanks David! I have heard about AST before, but frankly I know nothing about it. In your ref, there is a great survey paper by Steve Awodey, so, I will  start from there.  