# Axioms of Choice in constructive mathematics

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, axiom-of-choice, constructive-mathematics, proof-assistants

There is a widely accepted opinion that the Axiom of Countable Choice (further, **ACC**)

$$ \forall n\in \mathbb{N} . \exists x \in X . \varphi [n, x] \implies \exists f: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow X . \forall n \in \mathbb{N} . \varphi [n, f(n)] $$

is justified constructively due to certain interpretations of intuitionistic logic (for example, **[BHK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer%E2%80%93Heyting%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_interpretation)**). For example, [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22990/choice-vs-countable-choice) question already highlights interpretation of **ACC**. My question is more of a "practical" one: the best I hope for is to see an example of algorithm extraction from a constructive theorem which used **ACC**.

**ACC** means that if for any natural $n$ and any $x$ of *any* set $X$ there is a proof that $\varphi [n, x]$ holds, then there exists a *function* that produces $x$'s such that $\varphi [n, x]$ holds for any given $n$ as input. The catch is, a constructive proof already means a certain procedure of finding $x$ with the property $\varphi [n, x]$.

There have been, however, doubts in accepting **ACC** (or dependent choice) in constructive mathematics (see, for example, [1](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cee0/9ced16411609daeb6ea9546628f3bf16fc99.pdf), [2](http://math.fau.edu/Richman/Docs/Fta.pdf), [3](http://www.mscs.mu.edu/~wimr/publica/roots_new.pdf), [4](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-44622-2_35), [5](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397502007077), [6](http://philmat.oxfordjournals.org/content/12/2/106.full.pdf+html)). Since the question whether to accept **ACC** (or dependent choice) is rather methamatematical, I'd like to discuss its meaning in terms of algorithms (or computer programs).

Roughly speaking, if you "put" a proof on paper and everything is constructive, and say you used **ACC**, does it mean that it somehow hinders programming this proof?

The things I learned from the literature are:

**(1)** Some important constructive results rely on **ACC** or even dependent choice. It concerns the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, existence of bases of Hilbert spaces, existence of square roots of complex numbers, some facts about complete metric spaces. For example, [Bridges, Richman and Schuster](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2000-128-09/S0002-9939-00-05327-2/S0002-9939-00-05327-2.pdf) showed that the Bishop's lemma used at least a certain weaker form of **ACC**:

**Lemma**. Let $A$ be a non-empty located complete subset of a metric space $X$ and $x$ some point in $X$. Then, there exists a point $a \in A$ such that $\rho(x, a) > 0 \implies \rho(x, A) > 0$.

**(2)** There is a distinction between general Cauchy sequences and the so called *modulated* Cauchy sequences. The former have the form:

$$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. \exists N \in \mathbb{N}. \forall k,m \ge N. |x_k - x_m | \le \frac{1}{n} $$

whereas the letter have the so called *convergence modulus* $\mathcal{N}: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$:

$$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. \forall k,m \ge \mathcal{N}(n). |x_k - x_m | \le \frac{1}{n} $$

It is easy to see that both are equivalent as long as **ACC** holds. In particular, Cauchy and Dedekind reals are isomorphic. Consequently, Cauchy reals are Cauchy complete. It not the case if **ACC** does not hold as was pointed out by [Lubarsky](http://math.fau.edu/lubarsky/Cauchyreals.pdf). However, every modulated Cauchy sequence of modulated Cauchy reals converges to a modulated Cauchy real.

**(3)** **ACC** was given various interpretations. For example, non-deterministic algorithm, black-box etc. Some even claimed that **ACC** is in some sense responsible for "discontinuities" in computation.

**(4)** There does not seem to be a proof assistant which allows program extraction under **ACC**. In Coq, one can define **ACC** in the `Type` universe, but in `Prop` it has to be an axiom and Coq cannot crack it open to extract a program. I am aware only of results on "computational" content of **ACC** which use bar induction/recursion, fan theorem, Gödel numbering etc.

**(5)** In some formal systems, **ACC** and even stronger axioms of choice can be proven. For example, in Martin-Löf's type theory. Another example is [this system of Ye](http://www.phil.pku.edu.cn/cllc/people/fengye/finitismAndTheLogicOfMathematicalApplications.pdf) which is even weaker than Bishop's constructive mathematics. Theorem 11, item 16 has a form similar to a choice axiom. Consequently, [Ye, Lemma 27](http://www.phil.pku.edu.cn/cllc/people/fengye/finitismAndTheLogicOfMathematicalApplications.pdf) is the Bishop's lemma.

---

### Now, my question is

What exactly is **ACC** and what exactly is an extracted program from **ACC**? Are there any practical examples? What does it mean for a "realized" **ACC** to be a "black box" program?

**Particular question**: why does one need **ACC** to prove the Bishop's lemma? Take, for example, construction in Lemma 27 of [Ye](http://www.phil.pku.edu.cn/cllc/people/fengye/finitismAndTheLogicOfMathematicalApplications.pdf). 
He explicitly constructs a Cauchy sequence, which is even modulated in an evident way, and shows the implication. Where exactly is an ambiguity of choices?

---

**Remark**: variations of this question may already be found here and SE (for example, my own questions [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425311/hidden-usage-of-countable-choice) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426806/countable-choice-and-term-extraction)), but I still do not fully understand how to interpret **ACC** constructively.

Comment: For the benefit of the readers, could you please explain what ACC is? I am guessing that you mean the principle introduced by Bridges, Richman and Schuster in their paper you linked to, but it's not really clear from your question.

Comment: Pretty much  a duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22990/choice-vs-countable-choice, at least my answer would be a duplicate.

Comment: Good to see people reading Ye's work. I think those results should be pushed as far as they can go.

Comment: On (1), I don't see Bridges, Richman, Schuster stating that you need to use countable choice to prove Bishop's lemma; they just state that Bishop did use it.  You can eliminate the appeal to countable choice by replacing each decision of x < 1/n or x > 1/(n+1) with a decision about the mth approximant of x.  Indeed this is how Ye's proof works, where he uses (m) for that approximant, starting on the 5th line of the proof.

Comment: Matt, I don't see how your remark eliminates countable choice in the proof of Bishop's lemma. It's not only a decision that needs to be made, one also has to pick an $a_n$ in $A$ at each step $n$. Ye's proof uses the existence of a function $\delta$ to find such $a_n$, this existence is only guaranteed in Ye's system (where countable choice is provable), not in BISH without countable choice (unless you see something I don't of course).

Comment: I did not say that Ye's proof uses countable choice (!). But in general, $A$ is not totally bounded in Bishop's lemma. And then I see no way to copy Ye's strategy without countable choice.

Comment: I repeat: I never said that Ye's proof uses the axiom of countable choice (!!). Ye's lemma is however not the same as Bishop's lemma, since Bishop does not incorporate a witness function in the locatedness of A. In Ye's system countable choice is provable (*because* witnesses are incorporated into the definitions). Therefore Ye's system is not Bishop's system, and *therefore* in BISH I do not see how to avoid the axiom of countable choice in the proof of Bishop's lemma. I am quitting this question now, my efforts to help seem not to help at all.

Answer (score -2):

The following is a proof in Coq, or am I missing something?

```
Goal forall (X : Set) (phi : nat -> X -> Prop),
    (forall (n : nat), {x : X | phi n x})
    -> {f : nat -> X | forall n, phi n (f n)}.
Proof.
  intros X phi all.

  exists (fun n => proj1_sig (all n)).
  intros n.
  destruct (all n).
  simpl.
  auto.
Qed.
```

Comment: This is the axiom of choice in the `Type` universe, not in `Prop`. The notation `{x : X | phi n x}` is a dependent sum $\sum_{x : X} \phi\,n\,x$ whereas you asked about `exists x : X, phi n x`.

Comment: In absence of proof_irrelevance or classical reasoning or similar concepts, shouldn't be every proof of non-computational existence correspond directly and canonically to a proof of computational existence? On the other hand, at least as soon as one admits classical reasoning for Prop, it should be possible to set phi to, for example, the graph of some busy bever function, and therefore ACC cannot have computational content? (Not sure what happens when only having proof_irrelevance.)