# A geometric characterization of Rees algebras in categories without Choice

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, filtered-algebras, modules

Before asking my question, a caveat: The category theorist in me would like me to ask this question in more generality, but I will restrict my scope since what I'm really after is some geometric intuition.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring.  A *$\mathbb Z$-filtered $R$-module* is a diagram $\cdots \hookrightarrow X_{\leq -1} \hookrightarrow X_{\leq 0} \hookrightarrow X_{\leq 1} \hookrightarrow \dots$, where each $X_{\leq i}$ is an $R$-module and each map is an inclusion.  I will abuse notation and denote by $X$ both the diagram and its direct limit (the union of the $X_{\leq i}$s).  I am happy to assume that the inverse limit (the intersection of the $X_{\leq i}$s) is trivial.  The *associated graded* of $X$ is the $\mathbb Z$-graded $R$-module $\operatorname{gr}(X) = \bigoplus (X_{\leq i}/X_{\leq i-1})$, where the piece $(X_{\leq i}/X_{\leq i-1})$ is put in grading $i$.

The *Rees algebra* of $X$ is the $R[\epsilon]$-module 
$$ \operatorname{Rees}(X) = \sum_i \epsilon^i X_{\leq i}[\epsilon] \subseteq X[\epsilon^{\pm 1}]. $$
I.e. you look at the $X[\epsilon^{\pm 1}] = X \otimes_R R[\epsilon,\epsilon^{-1}]$, and inside it you take the $R[\epsilon]$-module generated by all elements of the form $\epsilon^i x$ for $x\in X_{\leq i}$.

Then the Rees algebra interpolates between $X$ and $\operatorname{gr}(X)$ in the following sense:
$$ \operatorname{Rees}(X)/(\epsilon=1) = \operatorname{Rees}(X) \otimes_{R[\epsilon]} R[\epsilon]/(\epsilon-1) \cong X $$
$$ \operatorname{Rees}(X)/(\epsilon=0) = \operatorname{Rees}(X) \otimes_{R[\epsilon]} R[\epsilon]/(\epsilon) \cong \operatorname{gr}(X)$$
Here the "$=$" signs are definitions and the "$\cong$" signs are canonical isomorphisms.  The first of these should be completely obvious; the second is an important calculation.

The Rees algebra has the following geometric interpretation.  The *affine line* is $\mathbb A^1 = \operatorname{spec}(R[\epsilon])$, and so any $R[\epsilon]$-module is a sheaf over $\mathbb A^1$.  Consider the sheaf defined by $\operatorname{Rees}(X)$.  The above isomorphisms say that $\operatorname{gr}(X)$ is the fiber of $\operatorname{Rees}(X)$ over $0 \in \mathbb A^1$, and (the union of) $X$ is the fiber over $1\in \mathbb A^1$.

Moreover, $\mathbb A^1$ has an action by the group $\mathbb G_m = \mathrm{GL}(1) = \operatorname{spec}(R[\lambda^{\pm 1}])$ given by $\epsilon \mapsto \lambda \epsilon$.  This action extends to $\operatorname{Rees}(X)$, by restricting the action on $X[\epsilon^{\pm 1}]$.  Thus:

> $\operatorname{Rees}(X)$ is a $\mathbb G_m$-equivariant sheaf over $\mathbb A^1$.

Since $\mathbb G_m$ fixes $0 \in \mathbb A^1$, the fiber $\operatorname{gr}(X)$ of $\operatorname{Rees}(X)$ over $0$ inherits a $\mathbb G_m$-action.  This is precisely the grading, wherein the $i$th graded piece is the weight space on which $\lambda \in \mathbb G_m$ acts by $\lambda^i$.  I have been told that one should think of $X$-as-a-filtered-thing not as the fiber over $1$ but rather as the fiber over the generic point in $\mathbb A^1$.

Now, not every $\mathbb G_m$-equivariant sheaf over $\mathbb A^1$ arises as the Rees algebra of a filtered $R$-module.  When $R$ is a field, I believe the correct statement is that:

> Over a field, the $\mathbb G_m$-equivariant sheaves over $\mathbb A^1$ that arise as Rees algebras of filtered modules are precisely the $\mathbb G_m$-equivariant vector bundles.

Put another way, over a field, there always exist isomorphisms between $X$ and $\operatorname{gr}(X)$ (i.e. trivializations of the sheaf near $0$).  The existence of such isomorphisms requires the *axiom of choice*, which says that every epimorphism splits.  But this description doesn't make sense in generality.  Hence:

> **Question:** When $R$ is not a field, so that I do not necessarily have isomorphisms of $R$-modules $X \cong \operatorname{gr}(X)$, what is the geometric characterization that determines when a $\mathbb G_m$-equivariant sheaf on $\mathbb A^1$ is the Rees algebra of a filtered module?

Comment: What seems obvious is that, if $M$ is the graded therefore filtered $R[\epsilon]$-module, then $X$ should be $M / \langle \epsilon-1\rangle$ and therefore filtered. Trying to get an isomorphism from there, I keep running into $\epsilon$ vs $\epsilon^{-1}$ issues that always bedevil me with these algebras.

Comment: @Allen: I also occasionally get confused with $\epsilon$ versus $\epsilon^{-1}$. I think I have done everything correctly, of course, but if there is an error, please let me know! The idea is that the minimum $i$ for which $x\in X_{\leq i}$ is also the minimum $i$ for which $\epsilon^i x\in \mathrm{Rees}(X) = M$.

Comment: What in the world does any of this have to do with Choice?

Comment: @JasonStarr The "axiom of choice" is a property that some categories enjoy and other categories do not. Category $\mathcal C$ "satisfies the axiom of choice" if every epi in $\mathcal C$ splits. I generally work with a category of Sets that does satisfy this useful property; then Vect does as well. But $R$-mod for $R$ a non-semisimple ring does not; neither does Top.  It was in that sense that I meant the reference to axiom of choice.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd: Okay, but what in the world does any of that have to do with your question?

Comment: In general categories, it's certainly not true that the a filtered thing is (noncanonically) isomorphic to its associated graded, and without such an isomorphism the geometric description I understand doesn't apply. Calling this property "Choice" is a cutesy term, but has good motivation. I tried to explain this usage at http://mathoverflow.net/a/22938/78; see also http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+of+choice#in_other_categories. Feel free to replace the offending statement with something banal like "This requires that every object is projective."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formulation: if $\mathcal{F}$ is quasi-coherent $\mathbf{G}_{m, R}$-equivariant $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{A}^1_R}$-module such that $\epsilon$ is a nonzero divisor on $\mathcal{F}$, then one gets a filtered module as in your question.

On the one hand, it is clear that the modules you've constructed have this property.

On the other hand, let $\mathcal{F}$ be such a quasi-coherent equivariant sheaf and set $M = \Gamma(\mathcal{F})$. This module has an action of $\mathbf{G}_{m, R}$ and hence comes with a weight decomposition $M = \bigoplus M_n$ (to actually prove this you need to do a little bit of work). Observe that $\epsilon : M_n \to M_{n + 1}$ as $\epsilon$ has weight $1$. If $\epsilon$ is a nonzero divisor these maps are injective and one sees that $M$ is the Rees module associated to $M_i \to M_{i + 1} \to \ldots$.