# Name for this generalized pigeonhole principle?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, partitions

For a set $X$, let $|X|$ denote its cardinality.
A block of a partition is a non-empty element of the partition.

> Let $P$ and $Q$ be two partitions of a set $X$.
>   If $|P| < |Q|$ then $P$ contains a block $B$ which intersects two distinct blocks of $Q$.

What is this principle called?

The proof is immediate for finite $X$, and is an easy consequence of the Axiom of Choice for infinite $X$.  I am interested in using this result, and would like to refer to its proper name and to cite it correctly.  Jech's *Set Theory* and several online sources don't seem to mention this result.  In particular the [Consequences of the Axiom of Choice project](http://consequences.emich.edu/conseq.htm) doesn't seem to list it (at least not in this specific form).

I would also be interested to know whether this principle is equivalent to some known consequence of the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: It certainly follows from "If $A$ maps onto $B$, then $B$ maps 1-1 into $A$.''  As I recall, it is not known whether the latter is equivalent to AC. 

Comment: I assume that by $< $ you mean there is an injection one way, but not  the other way.  

Comment: @Goldstern: I was using the notation from Jech,
where this means $|X| \le |Y|$ and $|X| \ne|Y|$: there exists an injection but no bijection.

Comment: I see; this is equivalent to what I said.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is equivalent to the Weak Partition Principle (a close relative of the Partition Principle mentioned by Goldstern). The Weak Partition Principle is form 100 in *Consequences of the Axiom of Choice* by Howard and Rubin (the Partition Principle is form 101).

The Weak Partition Principle asserts that if there is a surjection from $X$ onto $Y$ then it is not the case that $X$ has strictly smaller cardinality than $Y$ (i.e. $X \prec Y$). In contrapositive form, if $X \prec Y$ then there is no surjection from $X$ onto $Y$.

To see that the Weak Partition Principle implies your statement, note that if $P$ contains no  block which intersects two distinct blocks of $Q$ then each block of $P$ is contained in a unique block of $Q$ and the map $P \to Q$ thus defined is necessarily a surjection. By the Weak Partition Principle, this cannot hold at the same time as the hypothesis $P \prec Q$.

For the converse, suppose that the Weak Partition Principle fails as witnessed by sets $X \prec Y$ and a surjection $p:X \to Y$. Let $Q = \lbrace p^{-1}(y) : y \in Y \rbrace$ and $P = \lbrace \lbrace x \rbrace : x \in X\rbrace$. These are two partitions of $X$ with $P \prec Q$ and every block of $P$ is clearly contained in a unique block of $Q$.

Comment: This argument also shows that the principle is equivalent to the special case where $P$ is the partition into singletons. This special case can alternatively be described as the assertion that no set is strictly smaller than a partition of it. See how it is put by Dr. Strangechoice http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22927/why-worry-about-the-axiom-of-choice/22935#22935, whom I believe you know very well. In particular, the principle implies that $\kappa^+\leq 2^\kappa$ for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$. 

Comment: Thank you.  The citation seems to be to

* A. Lindenbaum and A. Tarski, "Communication sur les recherches de la théorie des ensembles", Comptes rendus des séances de la Société des Sciences et des Lettres de Varsovie, Classe III, __19__, 299–330, 1926.